# Why I can't use as delimiter in awk the string "?B?"

Tags: awk

By running the following I am getting as a result the string "utf-8"
I thought that with this command I would had string "tralala" returned

```
echo "=?utf-8?B?tralala" | awk -F "?B?" '{print $2 }'
```

Why is that?
What delimiter should I use in order to get the string "tralala" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk delimiters are NOT strings, they are "Field Separators" (hence the variable named `FS`) which are a type of Extended Regular Expression with some additional features (e.g. a single blank char as the field separator when not inside square brackets means separate by all chains of contiguous white space and ignore leading and trailing white space on each record).

The difference between a string, a regular expression, and a field separator are very important to be aware of. You sometimes also see the word "pattern" used - do not use that term, it has no (or too many possible) meaning.

A `?` is an RE metacharacter so you need to tell awk not to treat it as such in your case by either of these methods:

```
$ echo "=?utf-8?B?tralala" | awk -F '[?]B[?]' '{print $2}'
tralala
$ echo "=?utf-8?B?tralala" | awk -F '\\?B\\?' '{print $2}'
tralala
```

You don't strictly need to do that for the first `?` as it's metacharacter functionality is not applicable when it's the first char in an RE:

```
$ echo "=?utf-8?B?tralala" | awk -F '?B[?]' '{print $2}'
tralala
$ echo "=?utf-8?B?tralala" | awk -F '?B\\?' '{print $2}'
tralala
```

but IMHO it's best to do it anyway for clarity and future-proofing.

Answer (score 4):

`?` is a regex metacharacter that means `zero or one matches` of the preceding atom. (I'm surprised awk didn't complain about the one at the start but .)

Try `echo "=?utf-8?B?tralala" | awk -F '\\?B\\?' '{print $2 }'` instead.

Comment: (`+` matches one or more of the previous atom.)

Comment: Correct on both counts. That was a sloppy copy and paste that slipped a line and I clearly didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: And note that `?` after `+` or `*` acts as a reluctant  or non-greedy quantifier.

Comment: @AvinashRaj for perl-compatible or similar only.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr correct, that non-greedy stuff has nothing to do with awk. Etan - there's nothing wrong with having a `?` at the start of an RE as it's specifically defined by the standards as having no metacharacter functionality in that position, just like `*`, `+`, etc. so it's just a literal question mark character.